# willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString stops in the background

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am using willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString method to get the text position in my text to speech iOS app.

It had been working when I close the app in the background, but recently, I believe after iOS12 update, it started having the issue that it stops working in the background randomly.

Is there any way to fix this or other workarounds?
Maybe I should issue this to Apple?

Thanks.

**@Update**
I found that this issue tends to happen a while after audio interruption happened and I played the app audio again.

AVSpeechSynthesizer Audio interruption notification: {
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey = 1;
}

But, this issue won't happen always, sometimes.

**@Update**
I found that this issue happens in the Japanese language, not in English texts.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops working in the background **randomly**"?

Comment: Hi, it means this delegate stops working in the background a while after audio started playing, but sometimes, it keeps working.  It stops 5 minutes later, or 15 minutes later sometimes, but it keeps working after 20 mins sometimes. I still don't know how it will happen.  This issue never happened before, I guess it started happening after iOS 12.